# negative prediction for mixed effect logistic regression in R

Tags: r, prediction, logistic-regression, mixed

I have a data like this:

```
    Id  variable_1  variable_2  variable_3     y
134120      168.98       27150           3     1
134121      178.86       28650           1     1
134123      168.98       28526           5     0
```

I am using mixed effect logistic regression in r where the code is

```
model<-glmer(y~variable_1+variable_2+variable_3+(1|Id),data=mydata,family="binomial")
```

When I am trying to predict using the model using:

```
predict<-as.data.frame(predict(model,mydata,type="response"))
```

I am getting negative prediction values. Can any one suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: this is quite surprising.  The typo that @DieterMenne pointed out and that you corrected in your edit would be a very plausible way to get predictions outside of (0,1); if you *really* didn't make that error, then we need to see a reproducible example before we can help further.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your formula, it should be

```
predict<-as.data.frame(predict(model,mydata,type="response"))
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the rectification, but even then there is negative values in prediction. Not only that, they are greater than 1 in some cases.